# error in newff function in matlab: Undefined function or variable

Tags: matlab, neural-network, training-data

I write the below code to train neural network but it have error in last line

```
load('Data.mat');
load('Target.mat');

x = Data';

t = Target';

% Create a Fitting Network

hiddenLayerSize = 20;

TF = 'logsig';  

LF = 'trainlm';

net = newff(inputs,targets,hiddenLayerSize,TF,LF);
```

**Error message:**

```
Undefined function or variable 'inputs'.

Error in test1 (line 16)
net = newff(inputs,targets,hiddenLayerSize,TF,LF);
```

Comment: obviously you never defined the variable `inputs` which is supposed to contain the input for your network

Comment: now defined this but it have error yet!                                                                        Error in newff (line 101)
  out1 = create_network(varargin{:});

Error in test1 (line 17)
net = newff(x,t,hiddenLayerSize,TF);